# "Julie has cooked dinner Let's go and eat!" (PrPerf vs PrPerfCont)

Tags: perfect-constructions

Is it OK to use Present Perfect Continuous here, just like with "have you been crying? Your eyes are wet!" (crying-result-tears) ===>"Julie has been cooking, Let's go and eat!"(cooking-result-baked food).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the focus is on the result of the cooking, which is the cooked food, you are going to eat. So "Julie has cooked dinner" means something like: "dinner is ready, let's eat".

If you say "Julie has been cooking dinner" the focus is more on the activity of cooking, that Julie has been involved in. It is often used in a different context, for example:

Julie looks flushed, she has been cooking.

Something smells good! Yes, Julie has been cooking.

The kitchen is a mess, because Julie has been cooking.